# ¿Qué quiere decir «mamar gallo»? ¿Dónde se usa?

Tags: expresiones, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica, colombia

¿En cuáles países aparte de Colombia se puede usar la frase «mamar gallo»?

Suena vulgar pero entiendo que en Colombia no tiene un significado vulgar ([*“Esto no es una mamadera de gallo”*](https://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/esto-no-es-una-mamadera-de-gallo-duque-a-quienes-violan-la-cuarentena-para-viajar-en-semana-santa/662062) dijo el presidente del gobierno de Colombia, por ejemplo). Me gustaría saber dónde se puede usar la frase sin causar un malentendimiento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El diccionario de americanismos nos aclara que es una locución para indicar *burla* o *engaño* que es usada tanto en ambiente popular como culto (en caso contrario el presidente de un país no la usaría en declaraciones públicas):

> d. ǁ  [**mamar gallo**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=wdZCzravkx0AcxISHXo).
>
> i.    loc. verb. Ho, Co, Ve. **Tomarle el pelo a alguien; burlarse**. pop + cult → espon. (mamarle el gallo).
> ii.   Co. **Engañar a alguien con evasivas o falsas promesas**. pop + cult → espon. ◆ caramelear.

Un par de puntos más allá indica:

> f. ǁ  **mamarle el gallo**. RD. mamar gallo.

Y lo mismo con la expresión derivada:

> [**mamadera de gallo**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=osUxaMp3hx0A78aPiFw). loc. sust. Ho, ES, Co, Ve, Ec. Tomadura de pelo. pop.

Si hacemos recopilación de todos los países referenciados en el diccionario, tendríamos que se usa en alguna de sus variantes:

- Colombia
- Venezuela
- Ecuador
- Honduras
- República Dominicana
- El Salvador

Si le añadimos lo que referencia Wikcionario en su entrada [*mamar gallo*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mamar_gallo) vemos que el uso de esta expresión como sinónimo de *tomadura de pelo* o *broma* bien puede usarse en toda la América Central, Caribe y la Gran Colombia (Ec, Ve, Co).

Comment: Es perfecto. 1-Tomar el pelo. 2- Caramelear. Yo no tengo ni idea como lo tomen en esos otros paises, pero en Colombia es de uso normal en casi cualquier contexto.

Comment: @DGaleano ah qué bien. Recuerdo oírlo con frecuencia. La duda que me surge es: ¿se usa absolutamente de forma indistinta con _tomar el pelo_? ¿Se usa más uno u otro? Pura curiosidad. Por aquí se usa mucho _vacilar_ en lenguaje más coloquial

Comment: Podría decirse que son dos acciones que tienen el mismo nombre. Cuando alguien esta haciendo muchas bromas o _vacilando_ se dice que esta m.g. También cuando alguien debe estar haciendo algo y no lo hace o lo pospone sacando disculpas también se dice que está m.g. En cualquiera de los dos casos alguien podría decirle **"No jodás hombre, deja la mamadera de gallo"**