# ¿Es la palabra "correpto" una palabra verdadera?

Tags: palabras-raras, colombia

Estoy viendo la telenovela de Colombia que se llama "Un bandido honrado" que sobre un narco se llama Ortega, quien cambió de malo a bueno después de se conoció con San Judas.

En la programa se usa muchas veces esta expresión:

> Ortega es correpto no es corrupto

No puedo encontrar la palabra "correpto" en ningún lugar. Me imagino que solamente sea una palabra falsa que rima con "corrupto"

¿Es una palabra verdadera o no?

Comment: La gente en Colombia dice «correpto» por [*mamar gallo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34680/11102). Eso no es una palabra verdadera. Tambien pasa que a algunas personas se les dificulta la combinación «ct» y dicen «correto» pero igual, eso tampoco es una palabra verdadera. En el ejemplo de la novela es para hacer rima con «corrupto» y como te digo, por mamadera de gallo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard “correpto”/kɔˈrɛptɔ/ or /kɔˈrehtɔ/ instead of “correcto,”/kɔˈrɛktɔ/ not just once, but many times! However, in his debut I heard very clearly say -- Recuerde, es mejor ser correcto que corrupto. Spanish (auto-generated) captions say the same thing.

> Un Bandido Honrado: Mejor Correpto Que Corrupto (Música Original de la Serie de Televisión)
> Paola Jara & Caracol Televisión

And there's no such word as "correpto".

Comment: Siento que los subtítulos que vi se dice "correpto".  Pero ahora no estoy seguro.  Necesito sacar una foto de mi TV la próxima vez que verla.  Sin embargo los acentos  son estraños

Comment: ¿De dónde está esa cita?

Comment: @PeterM El título de la serie es "Mejor Correpto Que Corrupto", pero escuché dos veces "correcto".

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Bandido-Honrado-Correpto-Corrupto-Televisi%C3%B3n/dp/B07ST71C1G

Comment: Entonces no estoy loco!  Pero la palabra no es verdadera.

Comment: @PeterM No existe, tal vez es una forma deformada de escribirla.

Comment: Los neologismos espontáneos existen en español también ;)

Comment: Acabo de ver ambas palabras en los subtítulos: Correpto y Correcto